# Remove transparency in Histogram

Tags: histograms, charts

I have the following code, which places the data `s1, s2`, and `s3` on a histogram as shown below. I would like the transparency set to zero. How can I do that?

```
Histogram[{s1, s3, s5}, {Range[0.5, 1, 0.02]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"p", "Count"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1}, {0, 200}}, 
  ChartLayout -> "Overlapped"]
```

[image]

Comment: Add `ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[1]`.

Comment: Don't use overlapping histograms as they tend to be unintelligible (unless that is your objective) especially with "Count" being the vertical axis.  Overlay `SmoothHistogram`'s or `SmoothKernelDistribution`'s.  (With your data you might need the `"Bounded"` option as it appears that there is a definite maximum at 1.)

Comment: @JimB Could I pursuade you to demonstrate in my example? I have tried overlaying SmoothHistogram on the above but the lines generated are out of line with the Histogram. Would you need the data?

Comment: Sure. I’ll add an example with some made-up data that reasonably matches the histograms that you displayed sometime later today.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**  I used too large a binwidth for the nonparametric density estimates in my original answer.  Here I use the more appropriate `"Automatic"` choice.

Here is an approximate duplication of your 3 datasets:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
s1 = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[40, 1.1], 300];
s2 = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[10, 1.3], 500];
s3 = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[15, 3], 300];
```

And here is the associated set of overlayed histograms:

```
Histogram[{s1, s2, s3}, {Range[0.4, 1, 0.02]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"p", "Count"},
 PlotRange -> {{0.4, 1}, {0, 200}}, ChartLayout -> "Overlapped"]
```

[image: Overlayed histograms]

The interpretation is at best confusing because of the 5 different colors,  the vertical axis depicts counts (which doesn't account for the different sample sizes), and it just looks like a mess.  When one has large sample sizes and believe that the probability density is relatively smooth, one should completely avoid histograms and use nonparametric density estimates. (More sarcastically: one should strive to at least get into the latter half of the 20-th century.  Nonparametric density estimation and smooth histograms are not new.)

Here is a comparison of the associated histograms and nonparametric density estimates for the 3 datasets:

```
(* Histogram of counts using PDF for vertical axis rather than counts *)
h1 = Histogram[s1, {Range[0.4, 1, 0.02]}, "PDF", 
   AxesLabel -> {"p", "Count"}, PlotRange -> {{0.4, 1}, {0, 30}}];
h2 = Histogram[s2, {Range[0.4, 1, 0.02]}, "PDF", 
   AxesLabel -> {"p", "Count"}, PlotRange -> {{0.4, 1}, {0, 30}}];
h3 = Histogram[s3, {Range[0.4, 1, 0.02]}, "PDF", 
   AxesLabel -> {"p", "Count"}, PlotRange -> {{0.4, 1}, {0, 30}}];

(* Nonparametric density estimates *)
skd1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[s1, Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 1}, "Gaussian"}];
skd2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[s2, Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 1}, "Gaussian"}];
skd3 = SmoothKernelDistribution[s3, Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, 1}, "Gaussian"}];

(* Histograms and nonparametric density plots *)
Grid[{{
  Show[h1, Plot[PDF[skd1, x], {x, 0.4, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.4, 1}, {0, 30}},
     PlotStyle -> Red], PlotLabel -> "s1", ImageSize -> Medium, Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] &) /@ {"p", "Probability density"},
     AxesOrigin -> {0.4, 0}, PlotRangePadding -> None],

   Show[h2, Plot[PDF[skd2, x], {x, 0.4, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.4, 1}, {0, 30}},
     PlotStyle -> Red], PlotLabel -> "s2", ImageSize -> Medium, Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] &) /@ {"p", "Probability density"},
     AxesOrigin -> {0.4, 0}, PlotRangePadding -> None]},

  {Show[h3, Plot[PDF[skd3, x], {x, 0.4, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0.4, 1}, {0, 30}},
     PlotStyle -> Red], PlotLabel -> "s3", ImageSize -> Medium, Frame -> True,
     FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] &) /@ {"p", "Probability density"},
     AxesOrigin -> {0.4, 0}, PlotRangePadding -> None]}}]
```

[image: Grid of histograms and nonparametric densities]

So overlaying the estimates of the probability density functions makes a much cleaner and appropriate comparison:

```
Plot[{PDF[skd1, x], PDF[skd2, x], PDF[skd3, x]}, {x, 0.4, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0.4, 1}, {0, 30}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 14] &) /@ {"p", "Probability density"},
  PlotLegends -> {"s1", "s2", "s3"}, AxesOrigin -> {0.4, 0}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image: Overlayed nonparametric density estimates]

Comment: Particularly the green distribution seems not to convey the information of the histogram. But your help is, naturally, much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Good observation.  I used too large a bin width for each dataset (choosing 0.1).  That was a mistake on my part.  I'll fix things and use the `"Automatic"` setting  which I'm certain will be more appropriate.